# Эффект искажения Pixel art спрайта при повороте Unity2D

Tags: unity3d

На скриншотах персонаж с оружием, которое смотрит за курсором и при повороте на разный угол оно искажается. Как добиться такого же эффекта?
По стандарту в Unity при повороте спрайта он не искажается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы было "пиксельное искажение" - либо вручную создавайте каждое положение оружия в пиксельарте. Либо используйте шейдер, который будет картинку отрисовывать как крупные пиксели. Готового решения "из коробки" нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать анимации с "искажением оружия", следить из скрипта за положением оружия и активировать нужную анимацию. Для этого создав анимации, состоящие из одной картинке, в аниматоре создаёте int переменную, в скрипте в зависимости от положения оружия меняете эту переменную, а в зависимости от меременной будет решаться какую анимацию поставить, для этого достаточно указать условию перехода от any state к одной из анимаций, указав условием значение переменной как раз таки значение переменной. Это наиболее очевидный вариант, который реализовать сможет даже новичёк.